# Pandas condition across 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2

df1;

```
   A    B    C
0  11   22   55
1  66   34   54
2  0    34    66
```

df2;

```
   A    B    C
0  11   33   455
1  0     0   54
2  0    34    766
```

Both dataframes have the same dimensions. I want to say if value is 0 in df2 then give that value (based on column and index) a 0 in df1.

So df1 will be

df1;

```
   A    B    C
0  11   22   55
1  0   0   54
2  0    34    66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df1 = df1.mask(df2 == 0, 0)
```

For better performance use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2 == 0, 0, df1), 
                   index=df1.index, 
                   columns=df1.columns)

print (df1)
    A   B   C
0  11  22  55
1   0   0  54
2   0  34  66
```

Comment: wow, that's a cleaner than the if statements I was trying to set up. Thank you

Comment: @jezrael It should be `np.where(df2==0, 0, df1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df1 = df1.where(df2.ne(0), 0)

print(df1)
    A   B   C
0  11  22  55
1   0   0  54
2   0  34  66
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way -

```
df1 = df1[~df2.eq(0)].fillna(0)
```